# Can't install nixnote2

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 18.04

5 hours ago I could install it but now I can't:

```
apt-get install nixnote2
```

it shows:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  nixnote2 : Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install nixnote2`